# How can I redirect the save to reading list button to save somewhere else?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, safari, bookmarks

In the Safari search bar, there's a plus button that saves the current page to the reading list.[image: The actual button]

Is there any way I can change it to save to another Bookmarks folder or add a button from an extension to do something like this? I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Safari 14.0. I used Firefox before this but then found out that it makes my CPU work too hard so I switched to Safari. I want it to save to my folder called "Other" that FF used to save to.

Comment: If you press and hold the '+' it will list your folders in a drop down.  You then just move the mouse pointer to the folder and the link drops in there for you.

Comment: I did find out about this a few days ago, but I just want to know if there is anyway to just save to a folder on click, not hold and drag. (Yes I know, I’m being pretty lazy here)